# skimage - Contrast stretch using python

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, contrast, scikit-image

I am trying to preform a simple contrast stretch with python `skimage`, on the image opened with `gdal` as array of type `float32`. I first calculate the percentile with:

```
p2, p98 = np.percentile(arrayF, (P1, P2))
```

and then try to perform the stretch with:

```
img_rescale = exposure.rescale_intensity(arrayF, in_range=(p2, p98))
```

The returned image written to `.tiff` with GDAL contains only 'ones' and no data.

The cause of the problem might be in data range. For this arrayF it is between 0,0352989 and 1,03559. The script works fine when stretching the array with values 0 - 255.

Here is the function:

```
def contrastStrecher(Raster1, p1, p2, OutDir, OutName1):
    fileNameR1 = Raster1
    P1 = p1
    P2 =p2

    outputPath = OutDir
    outputName = OutName1

    extension = os.path.splitext(fileNameR1)[1]

    raster1 = gdal.Open(fileNameR1, GA_ReadOnly)

    colsR1 =  raster1.RasterXSize
    rowsR1 =  raster1.RasterYSize
    bandsR1 = raster1.RasterCount
    driverR1 = raster1.GetDriver().ShortName

    geotransformR1 = raster1.GetGeoTransform()
    proj1 = raster1.GetProjection()

    bandF = raster1.GetRasterBand(1)
    nodataF = bandF.GetNoDataValue()
    newnodata = -1.
    arrayF = bandF.ReadAsArray().astype("float32")

    nodatamaskF = arrayF == nodataF

    arrayF[nodatamaskF] = newnodata

    p2, p98 = np.percentile(arrayF, (P1, P2))

    img_rescale = exposure.rescale_intensity(arrayF, in_range=(p2, p98))

    del arrayF

    img_rescale[nodatamaskF] = newnodata

    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(driverR1)
    outraster = driver.Create(outputPath + outputName + extension, colsR1, rowsR1, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)

    outraster.SetGeoTransform(geotransformR1)
    outraster.SetProjection(proj1)

    outband = outraster.GetRasterBand(1)
    outband.WriteArray(img_rescale)
    del img_rescale
    outband.FlushCache()
    outband.SetNoDataValue(newnodata)
    del outraster, outband
```

I figured out that value of `newnodata` interferes with the calculation. Previously I assigned a velue of `-9999.9` to it and the results were as described above. Now with `-1.` it seems that the function outputs correct results however I'm not entirely sure of that as the `nodata` or `newnodata` value should not be included in calculation.

[image: Sample of the image:]

Comment: Can you please provide a working script + data so that we can help you debug?

Comment: The image should be a 32bit floatingpoint .tif.

Comment: You could try local adaptive histogram equalization

Comment: The image attached here is a PNG.

Comment: I dont know how to upload tif here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called percentile stretching where everything passed the bottom and top percentile designated will be mapped to 0 and 255 respectively and all pixel values in between will be stretched to improve contrast. I am not sure that is what you want but I believe that is what's done here in this example with downloadable code:  https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.9.x/auto_examples/plot_equalize.html
But you many not want for some images any mapping to 0,255 so maybe use `argparse()` to be able to enter these as parameters or use `np.amax` and `np.amin` to designate cut-off points, try writing the images to file and build an algorithm that suits your needs.